# How to align a text horizontally in the center of TextField when the input decoration uses suffixicon?

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

```
TextField(
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          onChanged: (value) {
            password = value;
          },
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Enter your password',
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
            contentPadding:
                EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
            ),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 1.0),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
            ),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 2.0),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
            ),
            suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.green),
          ),
        ),
```

This code gives the following output:

[image]

It is evident that adding a suffix has pushed the center aligned text to the left. How can I keep the text aligned to the center of the box, while keeping the icon?

Comment: Can you share the email ```TextField```?

Answer (score 0):

You can give a size to the icon and add the same size padding on the left side.